# Query against createdAt column in Parse

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have something like the following:

```
$q->greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', $formatted);
```

Where `$formatted` is `"2015-04-15 08:00:00"`

But Parse throws an exception `invalid field type for find`.

How can I query for objects based on `createdAt` dates?

Am using the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The date sent to Parse must be in this format: `2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z`

In PHP use this method to get a "Parse friendly" date:

```
$parseDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
```

If you need, for example, to query data from last 7 days, just use this:

```
$sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

Hope it helps.